# Sequelize password validation using len and setter fails

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, validation, sequelize.js

I set up the `password` field like below:

```
password: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING,
   validate: {
      len: { 
         args: [7, 42],
         msg: "The password length should be between 7 and 42 characters."
      }
   }
}
```

This works. However, when I add the `set` handler, to convert the password into an `md5` hash, the validation fails always (it ends with that message I set up above):

```
password: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING,
   validate: {
      len: { 
         args: [7, 42],
         msg: "The password length should be between 7 and 42 characters."
      }
   },
   set (pass, key) {
      // `key` is "password" here
      this.setDataValue(key, md5(pass));
   }
}
```

It seems to me like `len` and `set` don't like each another, but I can't understand why.

How to solve this?

Comment: I haven't worked in node.js (I came here from the mysql tag), but you should be utilizing something other than md5 for hashing (eg sha1) - especially if it's not salted. An unsalted md5 hash is insecure, but a salted md5 hash is very fast to generate, so a very large number of hashes can be attempted in a short amount of time, by somebody trying to break in. As for your question itself, is it possible to output what the length of the newly set password is (again, I haven't worked in node.js)?

Comment: @RobbieToyota That's a good suggestion, it's unrelated to my problem. I updated the title. It's related to setter, not to `md5`.

Comment: Since I have used the setters and validation alongside, can u try replacing the md5 function with a random string > 7 length. 
If u haven't done that already.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @bob_cobb Not really... I remember I found an alternative, but I don't know how I finally fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same problem, and I ended up creating a validation within the setter function:

```js
set(value) {
  if (value.length >= 8 && value.length <= 20) {
    this.setDataValue('password', bcrypt.hashSync(value, 10));
  } else {
    throw new Error('Your password should be between 8-20 characters!');
  }
}
```

This worked for my purposes.